# Visual Studio 2012 intellisense can see bootstrap on asp master page but not when working with forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, twitter-bootstrap-2

I encountered a problem when trying to design a asp web application.

after installing bootstrap with NuGet and setting up bundling I found an annoying issue.

When working on master pages intellisense can see and suggest classes from bootstrap however when I am working on the form pages intellisense cannot see any bootstrap classes despite the fact that the forms are using the master page with a working bootstrap theme.

typing in the classes manually will still work and the form pages will still inherit the bootstrap theme from the master but my productivity is hampered by lack of autocomplete.

I would appreciate it if someone can tell me how to make sure intellisense can see all the bootstrap classes in all form pages

Update: Looks like bundling is what was causing the problem and the only reason intellisense was still working on the masterpage was that i never removed the old link in the header